# How do I get request code for the new GoogleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog()?

Tags: android, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following [this guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup?authuser=1) to check for GoogleApiAvailability and it requires me to call `getErrorDialog(int responseCode)`

> however, the result code is SERVICE_MISSING,
>   SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, or SERVICE_DISABLED, then the user
>   needs to install an update. In this case, call the getErrorDialog()
>   method and pass it the result error code.

The guide is for getErrorDialog(int responseCode)
But [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil?authuser=1#getErrorDialog(int,%20android.app.Activity,%20int)) (hyperlink on getErrorDialog) says the method is deprecated

> This method was deprecated. Use getErrorDialog(Activity, int, int)
>   instead.

According to the documentation, the first `int` is a request code and the second `int` is the response code. I got the response code from `isGoogleApiAvailable(context)` but I don't know what the request code is and how do I get it.

This is my code:

```
  // Ensure Google Play services framework is installed
        int gAAResult = GoogleApiAvailability
                .getInstance()
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(gAAResult == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            Log.d(TAG, "Play services available");
        } else {
            GoogleApiAvailability
                    .getInstance()
                    .getErrorDialog(this, ? ,gAAResult);
        }
```

Where the question mark is to be replaced with actual request code
As a temporary work around I have passed 0 to it. I don't have a device without play services. On emulator, the app shows a dialog (without my code) to update play services. But the FCM documentation recommends to code this check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one int is a `connectionResult`, returned by `isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Context context)` method. The second one is a `requestCode` for error dialog.

After showing error dialog you'll get a callback within your activity's method `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int result, Intent data)` with a result and passed request code. As you might start several activities with some post-execution result form one, `getErrorDialog(...)` method ask you to pass a request code as a unique identifier of operation to help you process the result.

You actually need to implement this as the generic Play Services error dialog might help a user to update Play Services on his/her phone, so you got notified that issue was actually resolved. Same in case if you are not so lucky.

Comment: Ohk. I thought its the other way round. So this means I can define unique request code for every activity and use them respectively. Thanks!